# Finding the highest number of elements in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I  want to find the longest array and get his length.

This is array:

```
 [["667653905", "Johjn", "Smith"], ["500500500", "John", "Smith2", "Another field"], ["12342312", "asd", "asdasd", "fghfgh", "fghfgh"]]
```

Currently i am using loop but this is very slow solution if i have 50k arrays:

```
for(var i = 0; i<explode.length; i++) {
        console.log(explode[i].length);
    }
```

Comment: the slow-down is probably `console.log`, try concatenating the output as strings first - also why are you even outputting them to console?

Comment: Yes, the output would cost a lot, just add a middle result such as MAX, if you get the temporary best, save it into MAX.

Comment: How does calling `console.log()` find the longest? Do you mean to say that you visually inspect the 50,000 lengths and note the largest one yourself?

Comment: look into binary search and other search algorithms

Comment: I don't think there's any other way of doing it than with a loop since you have to evaluate every element. What you can do is cache the length of the array for(var i = 0, ArrayLength = explode.length; i < ArrayLength ; i++)  but that's going to be marginal at best.

Comment: or you can consider about using parallel programming. It would be faster.

Comment: @HaoyuChen ?? how exactly would one go about doing that in JavaScript?

Comment: @Pointy I just checked and found it was not a good option to run parallel in Javascript. But if the array is 50K, it may be better to move the code into the backend. Maybe it will be done by java or other low level language.

Comment: @HaoyuChen yes I definitely agree that the first thing to work on is avoiding that 50K element array in the first place :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the longest array with `.reduce()`

```
var longest = theArray.reduce(function(lsf, a) {
    return !lsf || a.length > lsf.length ? a : lsf;
}, null);
console.log("longest array has " + longest.length + " elements");
```

Comment: You don't have to pass an accumulator. If you don't pass one, the first element will be taken instead. Let's you get rid of the `null` and `!lfs` test.

Comment: @FelixKling I have an irrational fear of exploiting that behavior

Comment: Haha, that's a funny one! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just a complement to the answer above. If the array is 50K or more, it may be better to consider moving the code into the backend firstly. In that case, it could be done by java or other low level languages, or even using parallel programming solution. The speed will be increased dramatically.

Comment: Fair enough. But I think we gotta guess the OP nees to use Javascript to do so heheh

Comment: @lockedz What do you mean by OP?

Comment: sorry: OP = Original Poster (in this case, aka @mtch9)

Comment: OP = Original Poster. By the way you can do parallelism in JS using WebWorkers.

Comment: @plax still, most backend solutions (comparing parallelism with itself and non-parallelism solutions) would be faster, wouldn't they?

Comment: Thanks! I consider this. @Pointy answer works for me very well.

Answer (score 0):

You could only make an assignment (or output) fewer times, to boost it up.

Although I'm not a hundred percent sure the `if ()` would actually be faster than other aproach (as the use of `reduce()` [don't know it's implementation]), try this implementation with the 50k array:

```
var max = 0;
var explode = new Array();

explode = [["667653905", "Johjn", "Smith"],
 ["500500500", "John", "Smith2", "Another field"], 
 ["12342312", "asd", "asdasd", "fghfgh", "fghfgh"]];

var explodeSize = explode.length;
for (var i = 0; i<explodeSize; i++) {
    if (max < explode[i].length) {
        max = explode[i].length;
    }
}
console.log(max);
```