# In a frontend scenario, which approach would be faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, frontend

Browsing through a question ([Finding the highest number of elements in arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119889/finding-the-highest-number-of-elements-in-arrays/32120316)), this came to my mind:

What solution would be the fastest:

**Actual question**

> I want to find the longest array and get his length.
>
> This is array:
>
> ```
> [["667653905", "Johjn", "Smith"], ["500500500", "John", "Smith2", "Another field"], ["12342312", "asd", "asdasd", "fghfgh", "fghfgh"]]
> ```
>
> Currently i am using loop but this is very slow solution if i have 50k
>   arrays:
>
> ```
> for(var i = 0; i<explode.length; i++) {
>         console.log(explode[i].length);
>     }
> ```

**- First answer:**

```
var longest = theArray.reduce(function(lsf, a) {
    return !lsf || a.length > lsf.length ? a : lsf;
}, null);
console.log("longest array has " + longest.length + " elements");
```

**- Second answser:**

```
var max = 0;
var explode = new Array();

explode = [["667653905", "Johjn", "Smith"],
 ["500500500", "John", "Smith2", "Another field"], 
 ["12342312", "asd", "asdasd", "fghfgh", "fghfgh"]];

var explodeSize = explode.length;
for (var i = 0; i<explodeSize; i++) {
    if (max < explode[i].length) {
        max = explode[i].length;
    }
}
console.log(max);
```

Other has suggested sorting the array, but I'm guessing all kind of sorts are "slow" in this case.

So, which of these solutions would be faster for 100k+ values? Any other better solution?

*PS: the problem is not HOW TO do it, this is an hypothetical question, but just analyzing which and why one would be faster/better.*

Comment: Do you actually have data that contains 50-100K arrays, or is this a hypothetical question? Because you could check this on jsperf.

Comment: How strange it sounds, a simple `for` or `while` loop is faster than native JS mapping methods. If the array is large, you could use a WebWorker to get the result.

Comment: did you try  http://underscorejs.org/#max

Comment: @Andy I don't have the data, it's a hypothetical question I'm trying to analyze

Comment: @Asqan, that won't work in this case. That's for finding the minimum _value_ in an array, not the length of a nested array.

Comment: @Teemu someone mentioned WebWorker has parallelism. And, for real, I would have never guesses for/while are faster than native JS mapping!

Comment: Yes, WebWorkers are asynchronous, that might be very useful in a real case. Just search some tests at https://jsperf.com/, or create your own, you'll see the native methods really are slow compared to simple looping. This, as any performance issue, might be implement dependent though.